# FF addon toolbar - anything added sits on the right side of the toolbar

Tags: firefox-addon

I am having a problem with the firefox toolbar that I made. If I drag icons or say the search box onto it they all align to the left side of the toolbar and push over my toolbar icons over to the right. If I move the icons I dragged onto the bar to the right side of my icons they move back to the left side when Firefox restarts. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
   <toolbox id="navigator-toolbox">

    <toolbar id="TutTB-Toolbar" toolbarname="FreeLayer Toolbar" accesskey="T"
             class="chromeclass-toolbar" context="toolbar-context-menu" 
             hidden="false" mode="icons" persist="hidden" customizable="true" observes="cmd_viewrstb" inherits="hidden" >


        <toolbaritem>
            <toolbarbutton id="Back-MainMenu" type="Plain" oncommand="gBrowser.webNavigation.goBack()"
                           tooltiptext="Back">
            </toolbarbutton>
            <toolbarbutton id="Foward-MainMenu" type="Plain" oncommand="gBrowser.webNavigation.goForward()"
                           tooltiptext="Forward">
            </toolbarbutton>
            <toolbarbutton id="Reload-MainMenu" type="Plain" oncommand="BrowserReloadSkipCache();"
                           tooltiptext="Reload">
            </toolbarbutton>
            <toolbarbutton id="Home-MainMenu" type="Plain" oncommand="window.BrowserHome()"
                           tooltiptext="Home">
            </toolbarbutton>                                                            




            <menulist id="TutTB-SearchTerms" editable="true" flex="1"
                      minwidth="100" width="450"
                      onkeypress="objTutorialToolbar.KeyHandler(event);">
                <menupopup id="TutTB-SearchTermsMenu" onpopupshowing="objTutorialToolbar.Populate()" />
            </menulist>


        <splitter id="TutTB-ResizeSplitter" state="open" collapse="none"
                  resizebefore="closest" resizeafter="farthest"
                  tooltiptext="Resize the Search Box">
            <vbox id="TutTB-ResizeBar" />
        </splitter>


            <toolbarbutton id="TutTB-Combined-Button" label="Search"
                           type="Plain" tooltiptext="Search"
                           oncommand="objTutorialToolbar.Search(event, 'web')">

            </toolbarbutton>

             <toolbarbutton id="Loc-MainMenu" type="menu-button"
               tooltiptext="Actual Location">
                 <menupopup>
                    <menuitem id="web-location" label="Actual Location"
                    class="menuitem-iconic" tooltiptext="Actual Location" />
                 </menupopup>
            </toolbarbutton>  
        </toolbaritem>

        <toolbarspring />


    </toolbar>
</toolbox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your toolbaritem doesn't have an id which means that the toolbar customisation code can't persist its position.

Answer (score 0):

hey chris..
I am not really sure what you want to do.
But try using the align attribute for the toolbar.
Align is a general attribute which could be used to align various objects in xul.
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/align

Alternatively you could use the insertafter or insertbefore attributes to specify where exactly u want the toolbar to be placed.